# Almost sure convergence for lipschitz functions

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $x_n \to x$($x_n$ sequence of random variables) s.t $\sum \mathbb{E}|f(x_n) - f(x)| < \infty$. For any $f$ Lipschitz and bounded. Then $x_n \to x$ almost sure.
My attempt: As series converge, then $|f(x_n) - f(x)| \to 0$. Thus, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ almost sure. Can i conclude from here that $x_n \to x$ a.s?

Comment: $E|f(x_n) - f(x)| \to 0$ does not imply almost sure convergence of $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Comment: @JoseAvilez so how can i proceed from $\mathbb{E}|f(x_n) - f(x)| \to 0$? Or maybe from $\sum \mathbb{E}|f(x_n) - f(x)| = \mathbb{E} \sum |f(x_n) - f(x)|$ it follows that $|f(x_n) - f(x)| \to 0?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Markov's inequality, for any bounded, Lipschitz function $f$ and $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(|f(X_n)-f(X)|>\epsilon)\le \epsilon^{-1}\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{E}|f(X_n)-f(X)|<\infty.
$$
Thus, $f(X_n)\to f(X)$ a.s. for any such $f$. In particular, taking $f_N(x)=(x\vee -N)\wedge N$ with $N\in \mathbb{N}$, we get
$$
f_N(X_n)\to f_N(X) \quad\text{for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$ a.s.}
$$

Comment: so this implies $X_n \to X$ a.s?

Comment: Let $\Omega'$ denote the set on which the latter assertion holds. Then for $\omega\in \Omega'$ with $|X(\omega)|\le N$, $f_{2N}(X_n(\omega))\to f_{2N}(X(\omega))=X(\omega)$.